# Regarding reentrancy in C

Tags: c, reentrancy

If you have a function from a library `f_func()` and you know it's not reentrant, how would you use it in a threaded environment (POSIX)? You can't access the source code of the library.

Comment: You'd have to model it as a shared resource, and wrap it in a mutex (or similar).

Comment: Can u plz expain it in just a bit more detail plzzz

Comment: Which part needs clarifying?  "shared resource", "mutex", something else?

Comment: You can protect it with a mutex as others have said... but you may not need to if only one thread will call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it in a mutex. Here is an example usage:

```
pthread_mutex_t f_func_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_lock(&f_func_mutex);

f_func();

// if f_func has "side effects", such as setting a global, you'll want to grab
// the value within the locked region:
int local = global_set_by_f_func;

pthread_mutex_unlock(&f_func_mutex);
```